# Update Estimates in Party / Partykit model with averages from unseen holdout data

Tags: r, model, tree, nodes, party

I want to create a decision tree (using evtree which has a VERY LONG run time with large datasets) on a subsample of data.

I then want to take this model and update the terminal node estimates with estimates from hold out data. This is analogous to the concept of "honesty" in the GRF package where bias in model construction from sampling is countered by looking at hold out data. The end result in such a scenario would be a final model that is generally less biased, runs faster (smaller training input) and which has lower variance.
Ideally I'd be able to take the new model and inference new data on it.

```
library(partykit)
mtcars
set.seed(12)
train = sample(nrow(mtcars), nrow(mtcars)/1.5)
sample_tree = ctree(mpg ~. , data = mtcars[train, ])
sample_tree %>% as.simpleparty

# Fitted party:
# [1] root
# |   [2] cyl <= 6: 23.755 (n = 11, err = 224.8)
# |   [3] cyl > 6: 15.380 (n = 10, err = # 42.1)

data.frame(node = predict(sample_tree, newdata = mtcars[-train, ], type = 'node'),
           prediction = mtcars[-train, ]$mpg) %>%
group_by(node) %>%
summarize(mpg = mean(prediction)) %>% as.list

 # $node
 # [1] 2 3
 # $mpg
 # [1] 24.31429 14.40000
```

In this case I'd update the nodes id as 2,3 in the tree to 24.31429 and 14.40000 respective.

Things I've tried:
chat GPT 1000x, a lot of googling, jumping through hoops to figure out how to get terminal node values, etc.

---

edit2: this seems to work but I don't 100% understand why. Proceed with caution

Adapted from Achim Zeileis's answer

```
# library(evtree)
set.seed(123)
train = sample(nrow(diamonds), nrow(diamonds)/20)
diamonds_evtree =  evtree("price ~ .", data = (diamonds %>% select(any_of(c("carat", "depth", "table", "price"))))[train, ],
                          maxdepth = 3L, niterations = 101)

diamonds_ctree = ctree(price ~ ., data = (diamonds %>% select(any_of(c("depth", "table", "price", "x", "y", "y"))))[train, ])

refit_constparty(as.constparty(diamonds_evtree), diamonds[-train,]) #fails
refit_constparty(diamonds_ctree, diamonds[-train,]) #works

as.constparty(diamonds_evtree)


refit_simpleparty <- function(object, newdata) {
  stopifnot(inherits(object, "constparty") | inherits(object, "simpleparty"))
  if(any(abs(object$fitted[["(weights)"]] - 1) > 0)) {
    stop("weights not implemented yet")
  }
  d <- model.frame(terms(object), data = newdata)
  ret <- party(object$node,
               data = d,
               fitted = data.frame(
                 "(fitted)" = fitted_node(object$node, d),
                 "(response)" = d[[1L]],
                 "(weights)" = 1L,
                 check.names = FALSE),
               terms = terms(object))
  as.simpleparty(ret)
}

# works with "arbitrary data"
refit_simpleparty(diamonds_ctree %>% as.simpleparty, newdata = diamonds)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished by setting up a new `party()` with the new data and fitted values and subsequently coercing to `constparty`. See `vignette("constparty", package = "partykit")` for more details and worked examples.

I have written a short function that encapsulates the necessary steps:

```
refit_constparty <- function(object, newdata) {
  stopifnot(inherits(object, "constparty"))
  if(any(abs(object$fitted[["(weights)"]] - 1) > 0)) {
    stop("weights not implemented yet")
  }
  d <- model.frame(terms(object), data = newdata)
  y <- names(d)[1L]
  d <- d[, names(object$data), drop = FALSE]
  ret <- party(object$node,
    data = d,
    fitted = data.frame(
      "(fitted)" = fitted_node(object$node, d),
      "(response)" = d[[y]],
      "(weights)" = 1L,
      check.names = FALSE),
    terms = terms(object))
  as.constparty(ret)
}
```

Note that calling the `model.frame()` is important for potentially re-ordering and transforming the variables (e.g., setting up factors or logs on the fly).

For your data split I obtain the following:

```
refit_constparty(sample_tree, mtcars[-train,])
## Model formula:
## mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + drat + wt + qsec + vs + am + gear + carb
## 
## Fitted party:
## [1] root
## |   [2] wt <= 2.32: NA (n = 0, err = NA)
## |   [3] wt > 2.32: 17.664 (n = 11, err = 135.8)
## 
## Number of inner nodes:    1
## Number of terminal nodes: 2
```

In Node 2 the fitted value is NA because there are no observations. *(Maybe I did something wrong but I could not replicate the fitted values you show above.)*

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a test.

I tried re-running my code and also got the same issue for node 2. I'm sorry. Probably some odd oversight on my end. 

I'm going to update the example to use the set.seed(12) which fixes the issue. 

I'm going to give your example a run through. I'm cautiously optimistic and VERY thankful. I tried skimming through your other posts on here  before posting this question.


As an FYI, this might be a feature you'd want to implement somewhere. Imagine a use case where business rules are generated and established BUT you need to update the node estimates.

Comment: I've made an example of your function failing with evtree(), though it mostly works with ctree()

any ideas?

```
set.seed(123)
train = sample(nrow(diamonds), nrow(diamonds)/20)
diamonds_evtree =  evtree("price ~ .", data = (diamonds %>% select(any_of(c("carat", "depth", "table", "price"))))[train, ],
      maxdepth = 3L, niterations = 101)

diamonds_ctree = ctree(price ~ ., data = (diamonds %>% select(any_of(c("depth", "table", "price", "x", "y", "y"))))[train, ])

refit_constparty(diamonds_evtree, diamonds[-train,])
refit_constparty(diamonds_ctree, diamonds[-train,])
```

Comment: I've fiddled with this some more. 

It seems I have success with ctree based models. 
evtree objects all even though they have the class constparty. 
This is even though both

Comment: The problem was that `evtree()` processes its data such that the response comes last rather than first. I have made my solution robust to this now and `refit_constparty(diamonds_evtree, diamonds[-train,])` now also works correctly.

Comment: If you agree that this works correctly now, please accept my answer and simplify your question again. The current edits are too convoluted to be useful to future readers, I think.

Comment: Sorry for any delays, I seldom check SO. I really appreciate your efforts. I accepted your answer on principle (just figured out how to do that) and will streamline what I've written in a bit.

I recognize it takes effort to dig into things, especially for OTHER's odd packages that haven't been updated in 4 years. 

Thank you.